# Measuring external voltage on Arduino

Tags: arduino, voltage-measurement

I have a Logitech Steering wheel which I would like to interface to an Arduino whilst using it on a Playstation. My aim in the have the inputs from the gas and brake pedals light up a bar graph to give me a visual reference.

I figured the easiest way to do this would be to take two leads from the potentiometer in the steering wheel and plug one into analog input and the other into ground. When I measure the voltage from the leads using a multi meter I get 0.40v without the brake pressed and 2.70v with it pressed.

When I plug into the Arduino I get 4.4v regardless of the position of the brake.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

I have two wires coming out of the steering wheel (from the potentiometer) which I then put the positive end in an analog input and the other into ground on the Arduino.

Comment: Post a schematic of your wiring/setup.  That would save a lot of guesswork.  Even a sketch would help.

Comment: @almac, please dont use words, you have no idea how often that does not match what was actually done due to intentions. I would suggest Circuitlab.com as a good site to help draw a schematic you can share.

Comment: You don't know that a steady-input ADC is being used by the on-board electronics.  The implementation could, for example, be done by timing the charging of a capacitor through the variable resistance (analog joystick/paddle ports sometimes worked that way).

Comment: Thanks Chris, I hadn't thought of this. My next option is to use a usb shield and in use the ardiuno as a pipe in the middle, but this is going to be a lot more complicated.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you should use an opto-isolator to create a common ground between the wheel and the arduino, rather than just plugging ground into ground if you are not powering the arduino from the wheel.  The ground levels could be at different potentials which would, in short, cause inaccurate readings. May not solve the problem, but it is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this article](http://mrfahrenheit94.blogspot.com/2010/06/logitech-g25-racing-wheel-hack-for-xbox.html) it would seem that what you are dealing with is "3 pedals that have varying resistance whether it is the brake pedal, accelerator, or clutch." So you really ought not to be taking a voltage measurement to determine your interface characteristics in the first place. What you should be able to do, rather, is disconnect power or USB or whatever from your controller and see which pair of pins exhibits a variable resistance when depressed, and record the range of resistances that you measure practically. Then set up an appropriate voltage divider circuit per pedal such that you can read the midpoint voltage with the Arduino analog input in the conventional way. These sensors do not "output a voltage" they "vary a resistance" so you need to wire them up withe external circuitry accordingly in order to translate that varying resistance into a voltage response that you can measure.

Comment: A good suggesting for many purposes, but not here when the user wants to monitor the controls in parallel with their use by the intended game console.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have accidently set the I/O pin on the Atmel chip on your Arduino as an output instead of a logic input?  Or you may have accidently set it as an input but than enabled the internal pull up?

A skematic and a copy of your code would help debug the issue.

Comment: I did wonder this as the 4.4v - 2.70 = 1.7 internal voltage on the Auduino.I'm going to work out a schematic as I understand it's hard to help me without it. Thankyou for your help